# Why do we use "was" for the pronoun "I" in some cases?

Tags: difference, usage, verbs, subjunctives

Why do we use *was* for the pronoun *I*?

Can we use *were* or not?

What is the difference between *I was* and *I were*??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We use "was" with **I, he, she, it** when speaking of the past: it is the singular past [form of the verb "to be"](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm).
We use "were" with **you** and **they** and **we**: it is the plural past form.

But sometimes we can use "were" with **I** (**he, she, it**):

> I wish I **were** a sailor.

Here, I've expressed my wish to be a sailor, which I am not.

This is called *[the subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)*, used to express desires, wishes, intents. It is used to talk of "unreal" situations (that we wish **were** real).

This is the only instance in which we can use "I + were", and in modern English you can safely use "was" in its place, both sentences will mean the same:

> I wish I **was** a sailor.

An example of use of "I + were", from a [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Were_a_Carpenter_(song)):

> If I **were** a carpenter
>   And you were a lady
>   Would you marry me anyway?
>   Would you have my baby?

Here, the singer is *not* a carpenter, he merely speculates what might happen if he **were** to become a carpenter (or "if he **was** to become a carpenter", which is the same).

---

If I **were** you and wished to know more, I would read up on the subjunctive mood in Michael Swan's [Practical English Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_English_Usage), Topic 567.

Comment: "We use "were" with you and they...", and we?

Comment: Yes, and *we*, thanks for the observation, @rewobs!