# First and third person in second conditional exception

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

I know in the second conditional there is an exception about the first person.

For example: if I were (not was) you, I'd buy a new computer.

What about the third person? Should I use: If he were you... or If he was you?

thanks

Comment: A related question: "[Using Were with I](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38271/why-do-we-use-was-for-the-pronoun-i-in-some-cases)"

Comment: Google Ngram results: [If he was you vs. If he were you](http://goo.gl/jv2jZh); [I wish she were vs. I wish she was](http://goo.gl/ZNzJmd); [I wish he were vs. I wish he was](http://goo.gl/E1dS6b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If he **were** you...

Yes, in order to put a clause in the so-called **[subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)** you theoretically should use **were** with third-person singular subjects like "he, she, it". Wikipedia calls such constructions **[past subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive)**:

> The main use of the past subjunctive form is in counterfactual *if-clauses*:
>
> *If I **were** a badger, I would choose that color.*
>   *He would let us know if he **were** planning to arrive late.*

Quirk et al. also conveniently call this construction **were-subjunctive**.

In the overwhelming majority of non-formal cases, it won't be a big deal if you don't use **were** in such construction, though. You can use **was**, it will be considered slightly less formal, but acceptable. But see the P.S. section below concerning the expression "if he were you".

According to Quirk et al.,

> In nonformal styles, hypothetical past or indicative forms replace subjunctive *were*:
>   1. I wish she **was** not married
>   2. If only I **was** not so nervous
>   3. Suppose he **was / is** lost, what would you do?

P.S. Quirk et al. remark that in the fixed phrase "*If I **were** you*" the form **were** is still considered normal (at least it was in 1985, when the book was printed), so I guess it's better to use *were* in this phrase. They also note that in the fixed phrase "*as it were*" the form **were** cannot be replaced by **was**.

So it appears there are bastions where **were** is holding fast, like formal/fixed/often used expressions and there are areas where you can give yourself more freedom.

---

Reference: Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Ch. 3.62, "The were-subjunctive", and Ch. 14.24, "The present and past subjunctive".

Answer (score 2):

> 1. If I was back at home right now, I'd be eating my wife's lasagna.
> 2. If Barbara was any taller, she'd be too big for the car
> 3. If I were back at home right now, I'd be eating my wife's lasagna.
> 4. If Barbara were taller, she'd be too big for the car!

In old-fashioned, prescriptive grammars, people used to say that we should always use *were* in these types of conditional, for both first and third person singular, as in examples (3) and (4).

However, we now know that this is not a grammar rule of English. It is not even a good style rule.  The best and most famous writers in English have always used both *was* and *were* for the first and third persons, as in examples (1) and (2).

There are, however, some fixed phrases where writers have consistently used *were*. The best known example is in the fixed phrase:

- If I were you, ...

However, in actual speech, not writing, *If I was you* is actually extremely common. It is only in written English that we almost exclusively use *were* in this phrase.

Hope this is helpful!