# Do all hypotheticals use "were" or just counter-factual hypothetheticals

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, subjunctives

I understand that all hypotheticals that are counterfactual use "Were" because of the subjunctive mood.

> 1. If I were President, I would enact a great number of new policies.
>      (It's counterfactual because I am not president, right?)

I'm not sure what to do if there is a good possibility of it happening; do I still use "were"?

> 2. If I was/were going to the store tonight, I'd be sure to pick up milk.
>      (It's not nearly as impossible as the first example)
> 3. If he was/were at the mall with you guys, I didn't see him
>      (I'm not sure at all about ones like this)

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/38273/ (It's not a complete answer to your exact question though)

Comment: Possibly of interest: [4 types of conditionals](https://www2.estrellamountain.edu/faculty/stonebrink/ESL040/4_types_of_conditionals.htm). Note that only two of the types listed are for "unreal, imaginary situations".

Comment: Not so good at this, but this is all I can help *"irrealis were indicating that it conveys varying degrees of remoteness from factuality"* - A Student's Introduction to English Grammar

Answer (score 2):

*[WARNING: In what follows I discuss usage in "actualization" conditionals—conditionals like your examples, which assert that if the event put forward in the condition occurs then the event put forward in the consequence occurs subsequently. Usage is more complicated in "inference" conditionals—conditionals which assert that the truth of the proposition put forward in the condition entails the proposition put forward in the consequence.]*

There is more to this than a *was/were* distinction.

In this sort of non-past conditional *if I was* is a widespread colloquial variant of *if I were*, not a contrasting construction. The contrasting constructions are:

- counterfactual *I was/were* and factual *I **am*** in the protasis (*if* clause, condition clause), and
- counterfactual *I would* and factual *I **will*** in the apodosis (*then* clause, consequence clause).

Other things being equal, a non-past **open** condition—a condition whose factuality is not known—and its consequence are both expressed with the ordinary indicative form; the *if* is all that is needed to express the uncertainty.

> NON-Counterfactual: *If I am ... I will*

BUT: In this case other things are NOT equal: your use of *BE going to* in the protasis introduces another twist. You may know already that futurive *will* is rarely used in the protasis, and the same thing is true of *BE going to*. These futurives<sup>†</sup> are not used to express an **open** condition:

> <sup>∗</sup> If I will go to the store tonight, I will be sure to pick up milk.
>   <sup>∗</sup> If I am going to the store tonight, I will be sure to pick up milk.

Specifically, these futurives are used only to express a **closed** condition: a condition known to be factual, or accepted as factual for the discussion at hand.

> <sup>ok</sup>If, as you tell me, I am going to the store tonight, I will be sure to pick up milk.
>   <sup>ok</sup>If, as you tell me, I am going to the store tonight, I will be sure to pick up milk.

You appear to specify, however, a situation in which the factuality of your going to the store is **open**. In that situation you employ a simple present in the protasis, with inferred future reference.

> If I go to the store tonight, I will be sure to pick up milk.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Here and subsequently I specify *futurive* uses, because *will* (but not *BE going to*) has a couple of non-futurive uses which *are* permitted in the protasis: it may be used to express willingness or assent ("If you will pick up the beer, I'll bring chips") or, with strong emphasis, to express habitual obstinacy ("If you **will** keep teasing the cat you can't complain if she scratches you").</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers:

If I ***were*** going to the store tonight, I'd be sure to pick up milk. (It's not nearly as impossible as the first example)

If he ***was*** at the mall with you guys, I didn't see him. (I'm not sure at all about ones like this)

The first one is counterfactual and takes "were" despite the possibility as you put it in such with your construction.  The second one is talking about something that possibly occurred in the past; therefore, "was" is correct.

Here is how you could make it subjunctive, but it would change the meaning:

"If he were at the mall with you guys, I wouldn't see him (because I wouldn't be at the mall to see him).

This one talks about something that is either happening now or in the near future, but is counterfactual; it does not mean the same thing as your example.